# SQL append 14 hours if time is greater them 10 am

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can to check if the `datetime` field is less them 10am. otherwise is the next day.

```
SELECT IIF(DATEPART(hour,M.DateToShow) > 10, 1, 0) AS DateToShow
FROM MessageInfo
```

Comment: `IIF()` is from access. Real database engines use `CASE WHEN ...  THEN ... END`. But, to be sure, please edit your question to add the tag for the kind of database you're using.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn are  you sure?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: Huh... learn something new all the time. Finally just got Sql Server 2012 in June, so used to needing CASE expressions.

Comment: yeah IIF was three versions ago.  I guess even "real" database engines have IIF lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really about your needs but maybe this will be helpful or get you started.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(HH,DateToShow) < 10 then DateToShow
        ELSE DATEADD(DD,1,DateToShow)
       END AS DateToShow
FROM CardInfo
```